# как сделать очередь внутри команды play

Tags: python, discord.py, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

мне нужно, чтобы бы при повторном написании команды play видео ролик попадал в очередь и воспроизводился следующим, я пробовал несколько своих способов, но пока ни 1 не решил мою проблему.

вот код:

```
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, you not connected to a voice channel")
        return
    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()


@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_connected():
        await voice_client.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")

@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    try:
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
            server = ctx.message.guild
            voice = server.voice_client
            voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **ffmpeg_options))
    except:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")
```

Comment: Моё костыльное решение: `while connection.is_playing():` в отдельном потоке. Только очередь должна быть у каждого сервера своя и поток тоже свой.

Comment: у меня бот для 1 сервера использоваться будет, но я не совсем понял, как ты предлогаешь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно накидал. Это основа, на которую потом можно навешать всяких функций и т.д:

```
import threading
import time
import discord
import config
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio


class Player(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, connection: discord.VoiceClient) -> None:
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.connection = connection
        self.active: bool = True

    def _play(self, audio_source: str, loop: bool = False) -> None:
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio(audio_source, executable=config.EXECUTABLE_FFMPEG, **config.FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        while True:
            if self.connection.is_connected():
                self.connection.play(source)
            else:
                self.active = False
                return 

            while self.connection.is_playing():
                if not self.active:
                    return
                time.sleep(1)
            if loop:
                continue
            break

    def run(self) -> None:
        while self.active:
            with YoutubeDL(config.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
                audio_source = ydl.extract_info("(ссылка на видео)", download=False)["formats"][0]["url"]

            self._play(audio_source)

    def close(self) -> None:
        self.active = False


async def main(author: discord.Member):
    voice_channel = author.voice.channel
    connection = await voice_channel.connect()
    player = Player(connection)
    player.start()
```